# Datagridview Refresh window c# desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have three forms:

1. Form1 (Which is Mdi)
2. Form2 (child of mdi)
3. Form3 (child of Form2)

In my application Form1(MDI) open first,in which its child form (Form2) has open through menu, now Form2 has linkButton on which when I click a another form (Form3) has open.
Form3 has DataGridView1 which is bounded on formLoad of Form3.

What i want that after binding of DataGridView1 its 2nd row should come as selected.
For that I am writing this code:

```
DataGridView1.Rows[1].Selected = true; // 1 is the index of that row.
```

But this code is not working and the problem is that DataGridView is not getting refreshed.

Comment: Can u provide relevant code ?

Comment: @ coder sorry ,actually its very difficult for me place a code here ,it is quit confusing .Only thing i want , that my DataGridView1 is not refreshing ,even after using DataGridView1.Refresh() Function.Or you can say that my DataGridView1 is not Repainting again after setting Selected property to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I still get the problem, is the problem that you do the row selection on Form.Load event and it doesn't work? Try to use your code in `Form.Activated` event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind datasource occasionally

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = YOUR_DATA_SOURCE;
```

then

```
DataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0];
```